# Javascript trying to sort array of objects based on inner object array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, apexcharts

I'm not sure if there is an easy solution to this problem, but I want to sort an array of objects, that have a nested array of objects, based on this array of objects y value and the parent x key. The difficult part is that both of the arrays get combined together to represent some data.

Here is the data structure

```
series: [
  {
    name: 'testData',
    data: [
      {x: abc, y: 488},
      {x: def, y: 65},
      {x: ghi, y: 380},
      {x: jkl, y: 190}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'testData2',
    data: [
      {x: abc, y: 241},
      {x: def, y: 232},
      {x: ghi, y: 72},
      {x: jkl, y: 724}
    ]
  }
]
```

At this stage, there is only the two parent objects, so I need to compare each object and reorder them, the end result would look like

```
[
  {
    name: 'testData',
    data: [
      {x: jkl, y: 190}, // total for key jkl y combined values is 914
      {x: abc, y: 488}, // total for key abc y combined values is 729
      {x: ghi, y: 380}, // total for key ghi y combined values is 452
      {x: def, y: 65}, // total for key def y combined values is 297
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'testData2',
    data: [
      {x: jkl, y: 724}, // total for key jkl y combined values is 914
      {x: abc, y: 241}, // total for key abc y combined values is 729
      {x: ghi, y: 72}, // total for key ghi y combined values is 452
      {x: def, y: 232} // total for key def y combined values is 297
    ]
  }
]
```

I've tried a couple of ideas but can't seem to find a solution to my problem if you've seen a nice solution elsewhere please feel free to link it.

Here is something I tried

```
series.forEach(obj => {
  obj.data.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.y - a.y;
  });
});
```

But it just ends up moving the highest values in each array to the top, not the one which should match the other array. It's hard to give context but I'm using Apexcharts which uses the data to make a graph like this:

```
    | testData | testData2
---------------------------
abc  ------ GraphBar ------ 
def  ------ AnotherBar ----
ghi  ------ thirdBar ------
jkl  ------ fourthBar -----
---------------------------
```

So I need to figure out how to sort based on the bar's cumulative values, based on both the two objects data array y values.

This is what it looks like presorting

[image: Here is how the data looks pre sorting]

And after, as you can see its modifying the data

[image: And after my sorting]

Comment: question is not clear to understand what you wanna do. Please add  your code whatever you tried

Comment: Sort the parent objects, but based on what, exactly? I understand it has to do with the `data` array, but that's not enough info

Comment: I've added some more context if it's not enough I'll hack something together using a couple loops, I was hoping there was a more elegant solution using reduce / map operators

Comment: I saw that, but it doesn't really help. It feels to me like you want to sort by the total sums, but it doesn't make sense : the total for `jkl` is always 914, in every object. Sums are everywhere the same, you can't sort by that. So I still don't understand your sorting logic.

Comment: Does what I've added give more context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that we name the variable `series` as in

```
const series = [
    {
        name: 'testData',
        data: [
            { x: 'abc', y: 488 },
            { x: 'def', y: 65 },
            { x: 'ghi', y: 380 },
            { x: 'jkl', y: 190 }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: 'testData2',
        data: [
            { x: 'abc', y: 241 },
            { x: 'def', y: 232 },
            { x: 'ghi', y: 72 },
            { x: 'jkl', y: 724 }
        ]
    }
]
```

(note that I've made the `x` properties have `string` values instead of bare identifiers like `abc`; I assume that's what you want)

We can possibly tackle your sorting task like this.  First, let's get an object whose keys are the `x` values and whose values are the sums of the `y` values:

```
const sums = series.reduce(
    (s, r) => (r.data.forEach(xy => s[xy.x] = (s[xy.x] || 0) + xy.y), s),
    {} as Record<string, number>
);

console.log(sums); // { abc: 729, def: 297, ghi: 452, jkl: 914 }
```

Note that I'm using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) inside the `reduce` where the first part does the mutation and the last part hands back the object to be mutated.  It's not necessarily any better than using a `for` loop, other than being terse.

Now we can sort the `data` in `series` by using `sums`:

```
series.forEach(v => v.data.sort((a, b) => sums[b.x] - sums[a.x]));

console.log(JSON.stringify(series,null,2));
/*
[
  {
    "name": "testData",
    "data": [
      {
        "x": "jkl",
        "y": 190
      },
      {
        "x": "abc",
        "y": 488
      },
      {
        "x": "ghi",
        "y": 380
      },
      {
        "x": "def",
        "y": 65
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "testData2",
    "data": [
      {
        "x": "jkl",
        "y": 724
      },
      {
        "x": "abc",
        "y": 241
      },
      {
        "x": "ghi",
        "y": 72
      },
      {
        "x": "def",
        "y": 232
      }
    ]
  }
]
*/
```

Looks reasonable to me.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmAnAlvCMC8MDaBYAUDETAN4HEUxgCGAtvAFwwDkUaUAItVNcwDTlKRACbdqTPISGUSMAB5Nm1AEbB+MAJ5MALAA5dMAL4Cp04rIUth8AGbqtMAGwBWIybMULigOYALZPZMAMy6AAxugh6k8ooAVgDWADaBMACMAJzhhpGUALo5xjlkppQ09Ips0Fw8AEz8ORSiPBIN0l4sKmp8mkw12qkRJWbtzNZ23Q41QTWDUUQjfgETTADsM4VDbTEsCcnLMGvaRq1E+SXZ+GcEoJCwEACutOhYCChoAHSI8ML3wPAAFDl-hBuogAJSYAB8MH+iHeTWo7xsIEQAFFqMBfP85BooXBsDj3nJcpgYRACRoiSSAD7UmChCEAanklI0YO6EHZRUMMGo6AASvBQIhhAAeaAoMDebpgR7KJCQghggDcBGu4AgIES8HeiRA3mBj05ypgAHpTdFOqsaulumNeukVt1FjpnDVursmOlUkcLgRXqgIEiUejMf8AG548PwsTvTWIKD-f7UbrKCEYaEPJ7YZRUmAAWjgRuwiOJYJVavwN012t1+v+ACkAMoAeQAcnGoJLvMgbBpgUhAzL7olEt0auXVfhTQAqAiSeY5ABEZXgS6YS8qnDES-cxCXCPXOFaxTMS7kR6Xu13JxgS40R4yoVaGyEp+k58vnRvmyI96Pei6C+e6eLen4bosP5ng+wRhMBJ5gReG5jFBH4wU4zgvjkZxEK+pDLqul5btU1A1Khf6Hi0mzvkI4F3teIGUP+1raPB1GIV+qjkUx6F9KkbFvhxEH+NxFDMQcNQCTIQl3ihjFibx0xYSUOHHJcBAzqaQA)

Comment: Hey really appreciate the help, I'm just trying to fully understand the code, why is it we have the || 0, at this point (s[xy.x] || 0) + xy.y)? Is it to make sure it's defined?

Comment: Yes.  `s[xy.x]` will start off undefined so we need to make sure to initialize the sum to 0 in such a case.  If for some reason we needed to initialize to some other value than 0, then the nullish coalescing operator `??` would be better than `||` because 0 is falsy.